# Calling a Parameterized Stored Procedure in C# that returns values through a cursor and store it in a DataTable

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datatable, parameters, db2

I have a stored procedure that runs a select query through a cursor and returns the cursor (Original Select query is more complex, I have shortened it).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETASSIGNEDROLES(IN V_USER_ID INTEGER) SPECIFIC GETASSIGNEDROLES DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC EXTERNAL ACTION READS SQL DATA CALLED ON NULL INPUT INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE TEMP_CURSOR CURSOR WITH HOLD WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT ROLE_ID, ROLE_NAME FROM ROLE ORDER BY ROLE_NAME FOR READ ONLY WITH UR; 
    IF V_USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND V_USER_ID > 0 THEN 
        OPEN TEMP_CURSOR; 
    END IF; 
END;
```

Now, I could not find any example showing how to get values from a stored procedure that is returning a cursor. I believe it is the same as for every other stored procedure containing just select statement?

Also, my database is DB2 so the syntax is a little different. So far I have the following code after watching few questions on SO. But I didn't find any question using Datatable and passing parameters in CMD, is this correct?

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
using (var connection = new DB2Connection(ConnectionString))
{
  //connection.Open(); //open/close connection will be done implicitely by the DataAdapter.
  using (DB2Command cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
  {
      cmd.CommandText = "GETASSIGNEDROLES";
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter(DataBaseObjects.ParamVUserID, DB2Type.Integer)).Value = userDo.User_ID;
      //cmd.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout; //wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error in secs

      using (var da = new DB2DataAdapter(cmd))
      {
          da.Fill(DT);
      }
      DT.TableName = TableName;
      return DT;
  }
}
```

Comment: P.S. This is the first time I am asking a question, please go easy on me. I am new to this. Also, why is there so less on the internet for DB2. Everything is for SQLServer, very few articles related to DB2. Documentation doesn't have examples on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got this to working. About the open cursors, apparently that's how you do it in DB2. Cursor is left open for the client application to read from. This link helped: https://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/465403-how-do-well-anything-db2-sql

**Stored Procedure used (modified from question):**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETASSIGNEDROLES(IN V_USER_ID INTEGER, IN V_BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID INTEGER) SPECIFIC GETASSIGNEDROLES DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC EXTERNAL ACTION READS SQL DATA CALLED ON NULL INPUT INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE TEMP_CURSOR CURSOR WITH HOLD WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT ROLE_ID, ROLE_NAME FROM ROLE ORDER BY ROLE_NAME FOR READ ONLY WITH UR; 
    IF V_USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND V_USER_ID > 0 THEN 
        OPEN TEMP_CURSOR; 
    END IF; 
END;
```

**Function in C# to call stored procedure and save retrieved data in a data table:**

```
public DataTable GetAssignedRolesForUser(string ConnectionString, string TableName, User userDo)
        {
            //LogManager.EventLog("Inside GetAssignedRolesForUser");
            try
            {
                DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
                //See if UserID exists check is required here
                using (var connection = new DB2Connection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    //connection.Open(); //open/close connection will be done implicitely by the DataAdapter.
                    using (DB2Command cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = DataBaseObjects.spGetAssignedRoles;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter(DataBaseObjects.ParamVUserID, DB2Type.Integer)).Value = userDo.User_ID;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter(DataBaseObjects.ParamVBusinessEntityID, DB2Type.Integer)).Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessEntity"];
                        //cmd.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout; //wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error in secs

                        using (var da = new DB2DataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            da.Fill(DTT);
                        }
                        DTT.TableName = TableName;
                        return DTT;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //LogManager.EventLog("[Error] Inside GetAssignedRolesForUser: " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**Code to call the C# function:**

```
DataTable DtRoles = <Call function here>
                foreach (DataRow row in DtRoles.Rows)
                {
                    list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ROLE_ID"].ToString()));
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to study all of the related/linked pages of the Db2 Knowledge Center for your Db2-version that describe C# .net common language runtime procedures.

Start [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/t0011399.html) and study every linked page, make the examples work on your environment.

If your Db2-server runs on Microsoft-Windows, or if you installed the Windows-specific Db2-samples with your full data-server-client (default location is:

> \program files\ibm\sqllib\samples\dotnet\cs

) then you can see the DataTable examples for C# there, and also online in the Knowledge-Center - "DbDatMap.cs" and related files and  "SpClient.cs" and its dependencies

Please check why you populate `DataTable DT` but `return DTT`.

If you debug your code you should be able to iterate over rows in DT after the da.Fill(DT); completes successfully.

A consoleApp using most of your syntax works fine for me, the only variations being that I used a pre-existing connection, and supply a varchar parameter to my stored procedure instead of integer (but that cannot make a difference).

Comment: The stored procedure is complete and is already working with many of the pre-existing programs/utilities. Also, I want to use DB2DataAdapter rather than DB2DataReader as I do not want the result to be returned rowwise. I want it in a datatable. I already have a working code similar to this that just executes a query and stores result in a datatable, but I am doing this first time with parameters and returning a value.

Comment: "> You seem to be missing a da.SelectCommand before calling Fill."

I thought this is implied when I use the following code:
    using (var da = new DB2DataAdapter(cmd))

rather than using this:
    DB2DataAdapter da = new DB2DataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;